# display li items column-wise under title characters in php

Tags: php, html, html-lists

I have a php code as shown below in which through Line B, I have counted the title characters used while grouping array results in alphabetical order. 
Line A prints 4. [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/ecVj5)

**php code:**

```
<?php
$beta_lists = array (
    'Àpple' => 'http://www.abc.mno/apple/',
    'Ball' => 'http://www.abc.mno/ball/',
    'Builders' => 'http://www.abc.mno/builders/',
    'Bowling' => 'http://www.abc.mno/bowling/',
    'Correct' => 'http://www.abc.mno/correct/',
    'Campaign' => 'http://www.abc.mno/compain/',
    'Direct' => 'http://www.abc.mno/direct/',
    'Degree' => 'http://www.abc.mno/degree/'
);

ksort($beta_lists);
$groups = array();
foreach ($beta_lists as $title => $value) {
    $groups[remove_accents(mb_substr($title, 0, 1))][$title] = $value;
}

ksort($groups);
print_r($groups);       
echo count($groups);   // Line A

if(count($groups)%2==0)  {


}  else  {


}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that it prints the list items column-wise **(in 2 columns as shown below)** under title characters.

**The 2nd column should always start with a title character not with a list item**. For even numbers of title characters, 50% of the title characters with their list items should be on the left hand side
and 50% of the title characters with their list items should be on the right hand side.

In case if we have odd number of title characters (let's say 7) then 4 title characters should be on the 1st column and 3 title characters should be on 2nd
column **without any list being orphaned in the 2nd column**.

```
A                  C

Apple            Correct

B                Compaingn

Ball                D  

Builders         Direct 

Bowling          Degree
```

**This is what I have tried:**

The following html code needs to be integrated with the php code above for the lists to appear column-wise under **title characters**.

**html code:**

```
<ul class="shows-list">
    <li class="shows-list__letter">
        <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title"><?php echo esc_html( $title_character ) ?></h1>   <!-- For title character -->
        <a class="shows-list__link" href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"><h2 class="shows-list__title"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h2></a>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here **$title** is Apple, Ball, Builders, Bowling, Correct, Compaign, Direct and Degree.

Comment: Demo link seems broken.

Comment: Yes, there are some issues with the fiddle. It will be up soon.

Comment: Why don't you use css for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be extracting left and right columns into the separate arrays.

**PHP**:

```
<?php
$beta_lists = [
    'Apple' => 'http://www.abc.mno/apple/',
    'Ball' => 'http://www.abc.mno/ball/',
    'Builders' => 'http://www.abc.mno/builders/',
    'Bowling' => 'http://www.abc.mno/bowling/',
    'Correct' => 'http://www.abc.mno/correct/',
    'Campaign' => 'http://www.abc.mno/compain/',
    'Direct' => 'http://www.abc.mno/direct/',
    'Degree' => 'http://www.abc.mno/degree/',
    //'Example' => 'http://www.abc.mno/example/',
];

ksort($beta_lists);

$groups = [];

foreach ($beta_lists as $title => $value) {
    $groups[remove_accents(mb_substr($title, 0, 1))][$title] = $value;
}

ksort($groups);

$left = array_slice($groups, 0, ceil(count($groups) / 2));
$right = array_slice($groups, count($left));
```

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="shows-list">
<?php foreach ($left as $title_character => $meta): ?>
    <li class="shows-list__letter">
        <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title"><?= esc_html( $title_character ) ?></h1>   <!-- For title character -->
    <?php foreach ($meta as $title => $permalink): ?>
        <a class="shows-list__link" href="<?= esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"><h2 class="shows-list__title"><?= esc_html( $title ); ?></h2></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

And print the right column this way too.

Comment: hey, I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691611/how-to-allow-the-2nd-user-to-take-over-when-the-1st-user-is-logged-in). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63832946/8256347